# I requested my account on SO to be deleted, and it hasn't been

Tags: support

> This account is scheduled to be deleted Nov 9 at 10:26. To cancel deletion, click here.
>
> IMPORTANT: If you've requested deletion on other Stack Exchange sites, you'll need to cancel those separately by visiting each site's profile.

It's been almost two weeks and it's still active.

Please delete.

Comment: The people who can do that don't really look on MSO. Use the contact us link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I have similar situation. I wonder what's the reason: are there too many profile deletion requests, or do they try to manipulate statistics this way? Maybe we can force deletion by violating some rules:)

Comment: @Gimby apparently the people who do that don't bother looking at emails either. I'd say I'm disappointed with SO, but this is just "business as usual" now.